# syslog-ng activation fail

Tags: syslog

I installed `syslog-ng` on Ubuntu. I did this:

```
~$sudo service syslog-ng start
```

then I got in file `/var/log/syslog` the line:

```
syslog-ng[1150]: EOF control channel, closing connection;
```

I tried some solutions from the internet, for example modifying the configuration file `/etc/syslog-ng/syslog-ng.conf`:

```
source s_src {
    unix-dgram("/dev/log"); internal();
};
```

but nothing helps. Please, advice?

Answer (score 0):

which version of syslog-ng are you using?

Can you try changing unix-dgram("/dev/log") to system() ?

Comment: I tried it but it not help.